# Git rebase unexpected merge result

Tags: git, git-rebase

Assume the following commit structure:

```
A ---- B(HEAD)
 \ 
   C
```

File contents in these revisoins.

A:

```
1
```

B:

```
1
2
```

C:

```
0
1
```

I want to merge B to C. If I do it via `git merge C` I get an expected conflict. But If I do a `git rebase C` then git do it silently without any conflicts, but the result is unexpected:

```
0
12
```

Can anyone please explain to me why does it happen? Can I even rely on rebase? Documentation says that rebase reapplies commits on the tip of another commit. So how comes that commit adding "2" to the second line does not cause any conflicts and "eats" a line break?
You can test it on this repo https://gitlab.com/timofei.davydik/rebase_problem.git

```
git checkout test
git rebase master
```

Comment: I can't explain it, but I can confirm the behaviour. `git checkout test && git rebase master` was the command that created the `12` in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problems are caused by the missing newline on the last line of your file in each case, and possibly a bug with rebase when faced with that missing newline. Technically, a text file is not "valid" when its final newline is missing, which I suspect means that that case is rarely tested.

I reproduced the behaviour on your sample repo - thanks for prividing it! - and then created a different sandbox with the same files but with a newline on the last line at each state.

With the file-final newlines, both the merge and the rebase produced:

```
0
1
2
```

as you would expect.

I think `git merge` is seeing a conflict in your example because it's not recognizing `1` and `1\n` as the same, whereas `git rebase` sees "insert `0` ahead of `1`" goes ahead because it finds the `1` on the first line, even though the newline is missing from the `1`.

The fact that `git rebase` produced `0\n12` suggests it took the `0\n` and `1` from C and then `2` from B, with the newline missing from `1` and `2` because they are missing in your file.

I would say it's a bug for rebase to have considered `1` == `1\n`, but otherwise the output is reasonable based on the input.

Comment: Actually, a conflict is expected here, because revisions B and C add content to the same line (second one).

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares No, B adds a line after `1`, while C adds a line before `1`. If the files had its newline on the last line, as should normally be the case, there should be no conflict.

Comment: @joanis I like your explanation, thanks. I guess one should avoid creating files with no new line at the end.

Comment: Some of you guys could create an issue/PR at https://github.com/git/git

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `merge` and `rebase` won't move the things the same way. So, assuming you're currently standing on branch **B**:

- `git merge C` will bring the top state of branch C onto your current branch B. That's useful when you're working on a master branch and trying to aggregate the results of local development branches, for instance.
- `git rebase C` will move your full branch B on top of C (as a destination target). To do so, git will actually find all commits that are specific to B by browsing your branch backward until he finds the first commit being common to both your branches (here, the "A" point). It will then **replay** each commit of branch B on top of C, that is : reapplying every **changeset**.

This means first that a `rebase` operation is not a merging operation. Then, the changeset introduced by B is actually "adding a 2 right after the 1".

```
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
1
+2
```

At "A", your file only contains "1", so you'll end up with "1" "2".
At "C", your file contains "0" "1", so you'll get "0" "1" "2".

Comment: Your description is good, but the changeset from A to C should insert 0, not 2.

Comment: Sorry, the changeset is right for the command your showed. Inserting 0 is for `git checkout C; git rebase B`. Your answer would be more helpful if you showed that too, since that's the OP's question.